# Converting dates before January 1, 1970 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a column of dates into Date objects in R, but I can't seem to get the desired results. These individuals have birth dates before January 1, 1970, so when I use `as.Date` R converts a date like 1/12/54, for example, to 2054-01-12. How can I work around this? Thanks so much.

Comment: How can you decide what is right, e.g. in case `1/1/16`: Is it 2016 or 1916?

Comment: @christoph anything with a 2-digit year after "69" must be **18**70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is in the 1900s, its a one-liner - just format it with a two-digit year at the start and slap a 19 on the front and convert to a date. Again. Man this would look cool some %>% stuff:

```
s = c("1/12/54","1/12/74")
as.Date(format(as.Date(s,format="%d/%m/%y"), "19%y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "1954-12-01" "1974-12-01"
```

If years from "69" to "99" are 1800s, then here's another one-liner:

```
library(dplyr) # for pipe operator:
s %>% as.Date(format="%d/%m/%y") %>% 
     format("%y%m%d") %>%
    (function(d){
       paste0(ifelse(d>700101,"18","19"),d)
       }) %>% 
  as.Date("%Y%m%d")

## [1] "1954-12-01" "1874-12-01"
```

Note not thoroughly tested so might be some off-by-one errors or I've mixed months and days because you need to be [ISO8601 Compliant](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

No need for add-on packages, base R is fine.  But you need to specify the  century:

```
R> as.Date("1954-01-12")
[1] "1954-01-12"
R>
```

If you need non-default formats, just specify them:

```
R> as.Date("19540112", "%Y%m%d")
[1] "1954-01-12"
R>
```

*Edit:* In case your data really comes in using the `%y%` format, and *you happen to make the policy decision that the 19th century is needed*
, here is one base R way of doing it:

```
R> d <- as.Date("540112", "%y%m%d")
R> dlt <- as.POSIXlt(d)
R> dlt$year <- dlt$year - 100
R> as.Date(dlt)
[1] "1954-01-12"
R>
```

Comment: I think this answer does not help OP since you do not explain how you "specify" the century, that is, how you get from a string **vector** of format "%m/%d/%y" to "%m/%d/%Y". I am pretty sure OP is aware that `as.Date("1954-01-12")` would give him/her what he/she needs, but he/she does not have that format.

Comment: I added a base R way of doing that.  Still no need for add-ons.

Comment: That looks better!

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- as.Date("1/12/54", format = "%m/%d/%y")
year(x) <- 1900 + year(x) %% 100

> x
[1] "1954-01-12"
```

Comment: fails for dates after year="70". OP states birthdates are before 1970-01-01, so "1/12/74" should be **1874**

Comment: Obviously applying this on a vector would require a more robust solution, but I am pretty sure OP can write an `ifelse` or two to get there using the tools I have provided!

Comment: Thank you for your response. :-)