# how to handle incorrect value of difftime() function in R?

Tags: r, datetime, difftime

I have dataframe and there two columns of 1st_date date and 2nd_date. I used `difftime()` function to calculate the difference by days, and it did the job.
However, I found an incorrect value when I checked all values generated by `difftime()`

The incorrect value I have is:

```
    1st_date        2nd_date      time_diff
  12/31/68 12:11   1/13/69 19:29    -36512
```

while it should be:

```
     1st_date         2nd_date      time_diff
  12/31/68 12:11    1/13/69 19:29      13
```

the command I used is :

```
df$time_diff <- difftime(as.Date(df$1st_date, format="%m/%d/%y"),
                as.Date(df$2nd_date, format="%m/%d/%y"), 
                units = "days")
```

Any one can explain how did that happen and how to handle it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dates before January 1, 1970 in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508886/converting-dates-before-january-1-1970-in-r)

Comment: try `difftime(as.Date(format(as.Date("12/31/68 12:11", format="%m/%d/%y"), "19%y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d"),
         as.Date(format(as.Date("1/13/69 19:29", format="%m/%d/%y"), "19%y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d"), 
         units = "days")`

Comment: it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
difftime(as.Date(format(as.Date("12/31/68 12:11", format="%m/%d/%y"), "19%y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d"), as.Date(format(as.Date("1/13/69 19:29", format="%m/%d/%y"), "19%y%m%d"), "%Y%m%d"), units = "days")
```