# Convert multiple date format factor to date type in R

Tags: r

I have a variable in a data frame which hold different format of dates (month-year). for example. Jan-62, 98-Apr, March-1987.

The variable type is FACTOR at this point. I need help in converting this variable type to Date or POSIXct. I tried the function parse_date_time from lubridate package, it helped little bit but the year Jan-62 is taken as 01/01/2062 instead it should be 01/01/1962. I tried the function cutoff_2000 but I'm not getting the desired output.

Request your help.

Regards,
Aravindan S

Comment: For dates before 1/1/1970 see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508886/converting-dates-before-january-1-1970-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parse_date_time` and then subtract off 100 years from those components having a year beyond 2019:

```
x <- factor( c("Jan-62", "98-Apr", "March-1987") )  # input

p <- parse_date_time(x, c("my", "ym", "mY"))
year(p) <- year(p) - 100 * (year(p) > 2019)
p
## [1] "1962-01-01 UTC" "1998-04-01 UTC" "1987-03-01 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function as.date:

```
yourvariable<- as.Date(yourvariable, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

(m is month)
(d is day)
(y is year)

Comment: in your case, if you only have months and years: yourvariable<- as.Date(yourvariable, "%m/%Y")